# How does an Orthodox Jew view Saul's suicide?

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-saul

I read a verse...about king Saul committing suicide at the hands of the phillistines. I'm wondering if there's anything that defends his situation.

Comment: http://www.torahmusings.com/2012/07/josephus-and-the-sages/

Comment: There was an extensive article once in The journal of halacha and contemporary society about King Saul and Masada.

Comment: I'm uncertain if you're looking for a specific angle here by mentioning "Orthodox view" in your question title. The other uncertainty echoes what @Scimonster asked. Please clarify.

Comment: The Josephus and the sages link refreshed my memory it is viewed as self inflicted murder unless its to escape a worse outcome

Comment: I'm no Tanach expert... It might help potential answerers if you cited the verse you saw, chapter and verse

Comment: http://shaalvim.co.il/torah/maayan-article.asp?backto=11&ed=%E2%EC%E9%E5%EF%20%FA%EE%E5%E6%20%FA%F9%F1%E8&id=296

Comment: There is also the question of whether Saul actually died from falling on his sword or was just badly injured after which the son of the Amalekite actually killed him to take his head to David.

Comment: @Shokhet cited above. Strongs Chronicles 10:4 Then said 559 8799 Saul 7586 to his armourbearer 5375 8802 3627, Draw 8025 8798 thy sword 2719, and thrust 1856 8798 me through therewith; lest these uncircumcised 6189 come 935 8799 and abuse 5953 8694 me. But his armourbearer 5375 8802 3627 would 14 8804 not; for he was sore 3966 afraid 3372 8804. So Saul 7586 took 3947 8799 a sword 2719, and fell 5307 8799 upon it.(abuse me: or, mock me)

Answer (score 5):

The Midrash Rabbah (Noach 34:13) says אך להביא את החונק עצמו, יכול כשאול, ת"ל אך--in other words, the prohibition of suicide does not apply in the case of King Saul. Although the Midrash does not explain why the prohibition does not apply to the case of Saul, the simplest explanation would be fear of torture. This is the view cited in the Otzar ha-Geonim explaining the Gemara which says that Chananyah, Mishael and Azaryah would have succumbed to torture--the Otzar ha-Geonim explains that this does not mean that they would have been permitted to violate the prohibition against idolatry, but that they would have been forced to commit suicide so as to end the suffering: לאו למימרא שהיה להן להחיות עצמן ולעבוד ע"ז, אלא שהיה להם להרוג עצמן כאשר עשה שאול (quoted [here](http://shaalvim.co.il/torah/maayan-article.asp?backto=11&ed=%E2%EC%E9%E5%EF%20%FA%EE%E5%E6%20%FA%F9%F1%E8&id=296#_ftnref14)). 
This is also the view of the Ramban (in Torat ha-Adam, cited ibid.):

> וכן מצינו בגדול שאִבד עצמו לדעת מפני האונס, כגון שאול מלך ישראל שאִבד
>   עצמו, אלא שהיה אִבוד מותר לו, כדאמרינן בבראשית רבה אך את דמכם
>   לנפשותיכם אדרוש מיד נפשותיכם אדרוש את דמכם, יכול אפילו נרדף כשאול, ת"ל
>   אך.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have sources at the moment, but I seem to recall that some explain that Saul had specific license to kill himself because of he would have been captured, a tremendous *chillul Hashem* would have followed. (*Remember Samson's torture at the hand of the Philistines; something like that happening to the king of Israel would have been very bad*)

Comment: This is true --again, don't have the source on me this moment...

Comment: see http://seforim.blogspot.com/2009/08/some-literary-scholarly-halachic.html who quotes Haym Soloveitchik who quotes Tosfos who quotes a midrash about this

Answer (score 0):

Shulchan Aruch, [Yoreh Deah 345](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.345) deals with someone who commits suicide and also says that the suicide of King Saul was understandable, even if it was prohibited.

<sup>This answer is a carbon-copy of my previous answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85540/11486).</sup>