# Chamisha Va-arba'im Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred forty five?

### חמישה וארבעים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 345? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 345, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

The name of the guy who posted this question is Moses, and the question - it's name is Mi Yodeya. The answers can be named whatever you want, but make sure that they are not just about lazy gematria.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=8db52gYQGVkC&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&dq=managed

Comment: seems like a reasonable answer, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Ezra 2:34](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14260&st=&pgnum=121) & [Nechemia 7:36](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14260&st=&pgnum=209) both have the same verse.

> בני יריחו שלש מאות ארבעים וחמשה

Comment: Best one yet, although I suspect a simple Google search. :)

Answer (score 8):

345 is the gematria of Moshe.

This has added significance in light of [Chullin 139b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.139b.35?p2=Rashi_on_Chullin.139b.36):

משה מן התורה מנין בשגם הוא בשר

Where is there a reference to Moshe in the Torah? "Since he is but flesh" (Bereishit 6:3) [the word בשגם has the same gematria of 345].

Answer (score 2):

Shulchan Aruch, [Yoreh Deah 345](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.345) deals with someone who commits suicide and also says that the suicide of King Saul was understandable, even if it was prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Rambam's count, the 345th negative commandment is the Prohibition against marriage with two sisters.

(I know, it's a cheap answer that would answer every number through 613, but we seem a little stuck.)