# Rishonim regarding murder/suicide during the crusades

Tags: sources-mekorot

I heard there are Rishonim who dealt with the [murder suicides](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhineland_massacres) that took place during the [crusades](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusades), that there was disagreement whether those who committed these acts were correct  or not. I was not provided the actual sources. Where can these discussions be found?

Related to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61113/how-does-an-orthodox-jew-view-sauls-suicide) and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18019/masada-heroic-martyrdom-or-immoral-murder-suicide).

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/113457/759

Comment: See [this answer](/a/18020/170), my comment thereon, and, generally, the rest of that page.

Comment: @Double Yes, I've seen that. As noted in the comments there, why assume that happened during the Tosafists time? Or as pertains here, why assume it was during the crusades?

Comment: @Kouty Why assume that Daas Zkeinim (quoting the Orchos Chaim) is discussing the times of the crusades?

Comment: @msh210 That is one of the links in my question.

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/hamaayan/tesha-2.htm

Comment: @kouty Schoach! There are enough references there to write up an answer which I would happily upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1):

There is [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/hamaayan/tesha-2.htm) an Interesting article from Atar Daat that quotes texts from the Raavan and Tosfot Al Hatora about Crusades persecutions of Jews who died or commited suicide by Kiddush Hashem.

Comment: I'm upvoting this but cannot accept it, as the source seems to be the only benefit of this answer, not the answer itself. But thank you again.